# Textfield should edit global variable then and display it. But nothing or trash will be displayed

Tags: xcode, utf-8, nsstring, char, textfield

I'm writing a simple app that should control an Arduino via UDP. I've made two views:
- one for controlling (ViewController.h/cpp)
- one for settings inter alia the hostname of the Arduino. (Settings.h/cpp)

In the settings-view is a textfield and a Switch. If the switch is set, the hostname should be overwritten.

The hostname is declared like this in the ViewController.h:

`extern const char *host_name;`

And in the ViewController.m:

`const char *host_name = "WIZnetccef3";`

To display it in the textfield in the settings view I'm using the viewDidLoad function:

`textfield.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:host_name];`

The change to the view works fine. The hostname "WIZnetccef3" will be displayed.

If I change the position of the slider the following code will be executed if the Switch is on:

`const char *hname = [textfield.text UTF8String];`

`host_name = hname;`

But when I switch the views and come back to the settings no new hostname will be displayed. The textfield is empty or with strange characters.

This is my problem and I do not have any Idea what the problem is. I built in some errors to find out where I made the mistake but that wasn't helpful.

Comment: hi, I will look at the problem but this has nothing to do with Xcode, xcode is the IDE only -- not the sdk, nor api nor language

Comment: also i'd be good to say if it is mac or iOS :)

Comment: :-P I'm using a Mac Book Pro with MAC OS 10.8 and I try to write an app for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you reassign a CONST value ... my C isn't top notch but I think this is the problem.
ALSO you don't copy the value of the textfield, so it might not stay valid anyways

try

```
extern char *host_name;
```

and

```
char *host_name = nil;
```

and

```
if(!host_name) {
    host_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
    strcpy(host_name, :@"Wzeeee...";
}
textfield.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:host_name];
```

and

```
free(host_name);
host_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(textField.text.UTF8String)+1);
strcpy(host_name, textField.text.UTF8String);
```

Comment: disclaimer:typed inline. may not be correct! the point is that the char* isn't const and COPIED